# Terminating a random search

Tags: c++

I have a random search function. It picks a random number and searches the given container for that number. After enough attempts, I want to be able to terminate the recursive calls. So far to do this I've had to pass a third argument that I use as a counter. How can I create a counter inside the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print.h"
#include "random.h"
std::vector<int>::size_type random_search(std::vector<int> A, int x, int cnt)
{
    int i = random(0, A.size() - 1);
    if(A[i] == x)
        return i;
    else if(cnt > 500) {
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        cnt++;
        return random_search(A, x, cnt);
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> B;
    fill(B, 40);
    print(B);
    int index = random_search(B, 80, 0);
    std::cout << "position = " << index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I declare a variable at the top of the function, then for each recursion this declaration is overwritten and initialized again.

Is there a way to check if a variable exists if it has not yet been created? For instance I was thinking of putting in code like the following and not having a third parameter.

```
if(cnt)
    cnt++;
else
    int cnt = 0;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to use the third parameter?  You could look into declaring a `static` variable inside `random_search`.

Comment: Why is that recursive and not a function with a simple loop???

Comment: @DieterLücking. The simple loop worst case running time would be something like `O(n)` and recursive would be something like `O(nlg(n))`? `lg = log_2`.

Comment: @Comrade No, for this particular function, you're returning either after 500 iterations or when the number is found. That's still `O(n)`, and would be better written using a loop, as it doesn't involve all the repeated function call overhead (although a good compiler might be able to optimize some of that away). Recursion does not magically improve running time of an algorithm.

Comment: Fun fact: `n * log_2(n)` for `n > 2` is greater than `n`.

Comment: @twalberg. OK thanks. Yes that is what I thought initially that they were both `O(n)`. I am not dividing the array into multiple subsections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the default value for the `cnt` argument:

```
std::vector<int>::size_type random_search(std::vector<int> A, int x, int cnt = 0)
{
  // ...
}
```

Now you can call it from your main without passing 0 for the `cnt`:

```
int index = random_search(B, 80);
```